# Pandas take the line value below

Tags: python, pandas

There is such a model of real data:

```
    C  S  E  D 
1   1  3  0  0
2   1  5  0  0
3   1  6  0  0
4   2  1  0  0
5   2  3  0  0
6   2  7  0  0
```

С - category, S - start, E - end, D - delta

**Using pandas, you need to enter the value of column S with the condition id = id+1 in column E, and the last value of category E is equal to the value from column S of the same row
It turns out:**

```
    C  S  E  D 
1   1  3  5  0
2   1  5  6  0
3   1  6  6  0
4   2  1  3  0
5   2  3  7  0
6   2  7  7  0
```

And then subtract S from E and put it in D. This, in principle, is easy. The difficulty is filling in column E

The result is this:

```
    C  S  E  D 
1   1  3  5  2
2   1  5  6  1
3   1  6  6  0
4   2  1  3  2
5   2  3  7  4
6   2  7  7  0
```

Comment: Please improve the explanation of the data transformation, it's very confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with replace last missing values by original with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and then only subtract for column `D`:

```
df['E'] = df.groupby('C')['S'].shift(-1).fillna(df['S']).astype(int)
df['D'] = df['E'] - df['S']
```

Or if use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) is necessary use `lambda` function for use counted values of `E` column:

```
df = df.assign(E = df.groupby('C')['S'].shift(-1).fillna(df['S']).astype(int),
               D = lambda x: x['E'] - x['S'])
```

---

```
print (df)
   C  S  E  D
1  1  3  5  2
2  1  5  6  1
3  1  6  6  0
4  2  1  3  2
5  2  3  7  4
6  2  7  7  0
```